# Error: code in directory ... expects import "..." - what do I do?

Tags: go, import, package

I have project in Go. After I set up debugger and launch in Visual Code,
it failed with this error output. I am using go 1.13.4 in `/usr/local/go`

`/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/crypto/tls/cipher_suites.go:18:2: code in directory /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305 expects import "golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305"
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/crypto/x509/x509.go:36:2: code in directory /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/cryptobyte expects import "golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte"
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/crypto/x509/x509.go:37:2: code in directory /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/cryptobyte/asn1 expects import "golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte/asn1"
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/crypto/tls/key_agreement.go:20:2: code in directory /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/curve25519 expects import "golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519"
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:48:2: code in directory /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/vendor/golang_org/x/net/idna expects import "golang_org/x/text/internal/export/idna"
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/transport.go:32:2: code in directory /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/vendor/golang_org/x/net/proxy expects import "golang.org/x/net/proxy"`

Comment: It means you're importing the package with a different path. But since you haven't included your code, it's impossible to tell you exactly what to fix.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happen when you have a newer version of Go available on your `PATH`.

I worked around it by uninstalling Go 1.13 from /usr/local, but there may be better ways to handle it if you need to have multiple versions installed.

I had the VSCode Go debugger working with `go.goroot` set to a Go 1.11 install I was using for my project. I installed Go 1.13 into /usr/local to test out a feature and then ran into this same error.

If you have a different Go version on the `PATH` it seems like it's using that compiler, but compiling against the standard library sources in your other Go version. In later Go versions this directory has been renamed back to `vendor/golang.org`, and it doesn't recognize the `golang_org` hack that was used previously:
https://github.com/golang/go/commit/4d00937cecdea85b6f1eb894a6d28a53f5f2ff8a#diff-44c7c5a1dcc556d22e115d30ec0f11c9

I'm not certain if this is a general problem with Delve, or an issue with how the VSCode Go extension calls it, but the simplest solution in my situation was to uninstall Go 1.13 and the debugger started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the debugger. If you [would have searched for the key parts of these errors](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+code+in+directory+expects+import), you would have discovered that the error is due to the fact since v1.4 Go supports so-called ["canonical imports"](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#canonicalimports).

Most probably some packages in your project were vendored using their "hosting" URLs (such as `github.com/what/ever`) instead of their canonical URLs suggested by the error message.

The proper solution is to revendor the affecting packages the correct way.

If you merely want the code to build "as is" no matter what, you could edit the code of these packages to remove "canonical import comments" from them.

Comment: @Coolman, please do not let "quickly ask on SO without putting any thought into the problem" be your main problem-solving tactic—it's impossibe to become proficient in software engeneering while posessing this anti-skill. Please read [this](https://whathaveyoutried.com/) for more background.

Comment: While these suggestions are probably helpful for other vendoring problems, it's not as obvious here since the problem is actually with packages vendored in the Go standard library (`go-1.10/src/vendor/golang_org`). It does also happen specifically with the debugger. As I mentioned in my answer I'm not certain if it's general problem with Delve or just how VSCode is calling it. The OP could have provided more details, but the answer isn't as obvious in this situation since it isn't from packages in their own project, but an odd interaction between multiple Go versions and the debugger.

Comment: I too get the message that my code "expects" an import. What does it mean that code "expects" something? It seems to be finding the package - when I change the name I am trying to import, I get a different message, so that means that it sees the package I guess. So what is the expectation and what does it mean that the expectaition is not fulfiled. THe package I am trying to import is the standard tutorial package rsc.io/quote –

Comment: Hi, @AnnaNaden! Have you read that bit about canonical imports I gave a link to in my answer? I'm asking because your remarks appear to me as if you are not familiar with what "canonical imports" are about, which is a bit strange given the current context.

Comment: @kostix, I read it but it was difficult to relate it to my problem. It sounds like perhaps the messages "code expects import..." is the refusal to import that is mentioned in the reference you provided. Is that right? *My question is how to interepret the "code expects import..." message. The reference says to remove a package "manually." I don't know what that means. Presumably there are some files there that one deletes and that is "manual removal." Is that right?

Comment: @AnnaNaden, can you re-ask your question using [a venue other than SO](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community)? Solving your issues requires multiple backs-and-forths, and SO is absolutely unfit for such exchanges (and they are actually prohibited by the rules). `r/golang` on Reddit or the mailing list would be fine. Please be sure to include exact names of packages and error messages. A piece of code which could be used to recreate the problem would be ideal.